# Differences between CSS selectors

Tags: html, css

I do not know if this question has been asked before or not but right now I'm writing some css stylesheets like this

```
[myclass]{
/*some styles*/
}
```

**html**

```
<div myclass></div>
```

but I know many people write like this

```
.myclass{
    /*some styles*/
    }
```

**html**

```
<div class="myclass"></div>
```

What's the difference? Maybe some browsers support or not? or what about mobiles do they support it? Is it legal css style script?

Comment: The best way is `.myclass`, as `[myclass]` is for HTML attributes. Also, people can find it harder to understand your code.

Comment: @Tobsta is it some kind of unwritten rule for css to declaring with dot or hashtag?

Comment: @Shaxrillo hashtags are used to reference the `id` value of an element. Where dots are used to reference the `class` value

Comment: @DrewHammond I know but declaring pure css stylsheet which one better with dot or attr?

Comment: @Shaxrillo `#example{ ... }` would style the only element with an `id='example'`. `.example{ ... }` will style any element containing `class='example'`.

Comment: @Shaxrillo Check out [this article](http://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/) on performance of using various types of CSS selectors. Attribute selectors are slower than single class selectors. Single class selectors are slower than id selectors

Comment: @torazaburo Simply these people do not understand my question. I have been coding for many years. Simply when I write some codes in `angular material` I found they widely used attribute styles. Then I simply asked then they started to teach me about ids and classes :D That's it.

Comment: @DrewHammond The page you reference itself states: "For me, it has confirmed my belief that it is absolute folly to worry about the type of selector used."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[myclass]` selector in your first example is not for classes, but rather other HTML attributes. See [Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for more details.

Comment: is there any restrictions about browser support?

Comment: @Shaxrillo Here's the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Yes, we know that `[...]` is an attribute selector. The point is that the OP is proposing using attributes as a sort of proxy for or alternative to classes. The question is not does this work (it does), but if it's legal and supported (answer: it's not "legal" in the sense that it will fail validation, but it's legal in the sense of being valid syntactically; and yes, it is supported). The unstated questions are really "is it a good idea", and perhaps, "are there performance implications" (answer: no, and probably not).

Answer (score 1):

Although all browsers would support this attribute-based approach to "classes", and there are probably no meaningful performance differences, it's invalid HTML (will fail validation). It's a style I hadn't seen before, and the reason is that it is a bad idea. Classes have been around for years and have all kinds of supporting machinery and are understood by any beginning HTML programmer.

For instance, with "normal" class usage, you can use `elt.classList.add`, or `$(elt).addClass`, and add multiple classes at a time, and toggle them, and get the whole list with `elt.className`, and get elements with `getElementsbyClassName`. None of this machinery is available for your "class as attribute" animals. You'll have to use `elt.removeAttribute` to get rid of them one at a time, and then `elt.setAttribute` to add them back, use `querySelectorAll('[myClass]')` to look for them, etc.

Comment: I don't see no elegance writing invalid HTML to implement a solution that can be achieved with more graceful and widely used notation. I just see a few characters less, but with a possibly high cost. If there's probably no meaningful perfromance impact on a tiny scale, on a larger scale it's another story. You also point other possible issues so I don't understand why your answer seems so open to such code... It is also obvious from the question "What's the difference?" from the OP he doesn't have such a good idea what he's doing, which may be a bigger issue if he continues that way...

Comment: Point well taken. I did start off my answer by saying "It's invalid HTML". I have edited my answer.

Comment: I like the Edit you made, +1 instead of -1 then :-) I'm not a validation-nazi, valid code is not an end in itself and with evolving standards what is valid today may be invalid tomorrow and vice versa, but I don't think we should ever advise to write invalid code just for personnal preference purpose. In the end the OP might realize how wrong he was and have a hard time going back while it's much easier to use common best-practices from the beginning.